# How to append five random elements from one 5-element list to another list without adding any duplicates?

Tags: python, list, loops, random

```
def f1():
    a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
    def f2():
        b = []
       
        for i in range(5):
            if random.choice(a) not in b:
                b.append(random.choice(a))
            else:
                return f2()
        print(b)
    f2()
f1()
```

I know that random.choice(a) will change every time it is ran but I need to check a random.choice(a) and append that same random.choice(a) to a list if it is not already present.

Comment: 5 random elements from 5 elements without duplicates are these 5 elements. Are you looking for [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)?

Comment: You should use: `b = random.sample(a, len(a))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use random sample to create a new shuffled list:

```py
def f1():
    a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
    def f2():
        b = random.sample(a, len(a))
                
        print(b)
    f2()
f1()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def f(l):
  l1=[]
  for i in range(1,6):
       if random.choice(l) not in l1:
             l1.append(random.choice(l)
       else:
             return f(l)
l=["one","two","three","four","five"]
f(l)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.